# swift iOS : Get image from gallery by created date

Tags: ios, swift, image

I am having some problem in backup of gallery camera photos to server through backend thread. In iOS am not getting any particular image path for the camera images, so how can I keep track of which Image is uploaded or not through database ?

So my plan is I will get image creation date by phassets add it to database & select one by one image & upload it to server and keep sync flag. but let's say in middle some image upload is failed, then at this time am having image creation date only, so how I can access only that particular image from gallery ? how usually people will do photo synch in ios swift ?

Answer (score 0):

```
let date:NSDate = (asset.valueForProperty(ALAssetPropertyDate))
```

the above line return the date for the particular asset.

Make a sorting over the list of dates.

i hope this will help you..

Comment: Am not clarified with your answer, but how this will help me getting image for particular date ?

Comment: Make a loop to get the assets and sort it out based on the date property.From the list get the asset that you are looking for..